# Are companies allowed to file consumer complaints to the Federal Communications Commission?

Tags: united-states, consumer-protection, fcc

Are companies allowed to file consumer complaints to the Federal Communications Commission? May a company complain to the FCC that their business phone provider won't give them the information needed to port a number or they're overcharged for internet?

Answer (score 1):

There is no legal significance to their use of the word "consumer" rather than "customer" or "purchaser", and nothing on [their website](https://consumercomplaints.fcc.gov/hc/en-us) suggests a limit on who can file a complaint. Indeed, the [complaint form](https://consumercomplaints.fcc.gov/hc/en-us/article_attachments/360090262251/complaint_form.pdf) asks for "Company Name (if applicable)". There are no subject-matter restrictions on complaints though it is pointless to complain about something that isn't about a violation of FCC regulations. It *is* pointless to complain about internet service rates, because the FCC does not regulate those rates. I cannot determine if there is any FCC requirement that a provider must tell you how to port your number from one provider to another. However, you could file a complains, which the provider must reply to, and they would tell you something like "We don't provide that information". You could then escalate the matter to the status of a formal complaint (which costs money), and eventually you might get a full formal explanation that they are not required to tell you how to do it (unless they *are* required to, then they presumably will have told you before you got to this stage). The [FCC guide on porting numbers](https://www.fcc.gov/consumers/guides/porting-keeping-your-phone-number-when-you-change-providers) does not indicate whether the provider has to explain to you how to do it, but their guide is a good starting point.